# Why can I not leave EventListener into a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript and wanted to ask a question related to some examples I'm looking through.

I am making a game where the user has 10 tries to guess a number and if he succeeds he gets a "You win message" if not "game over". **My question is why does the program not work when I leave `guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess);` in the `function checkGuess()`. And when I write it outside of the function it works**. Sorry if the question is silly, but I don't understand why I cannot leave the EventListener in the function. I hope someone more competent could explain.
HTML and JavaScript:

```
<body>
    <div class="resultParas">
        <p class="guesses"></p>
        <p class="lastResult"></p>
        <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
    </div>

<label for="guessField">Enter a guess: </label>
<input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
<input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">

<script>
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    const guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
    const lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
    const lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');
    const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
    const guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');

    let guessCount = 1;
    let resetButton;

    function checkGuess(){

        let userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
        if(guessCount === 1){
            guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
        }
        guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';

        if(userGuess === randomNumber){
            lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
            lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            lowOrHi.textContent = '';
            setGameOver();
        }else if(guessCount === 10){
            lastResult.textContent = 'Game Over';
            setGameOver();
        }else{
            lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
            lastResult.style.backgroundColor ='red';
            if(userGuess < randomNumber){
                lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low';
            }else if(userGuess > randomNumber){
                lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high';
            }
        }
        guessCount++;
        guessField.value = ' ';
        guessField.focus();
    }

    guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess);

    function setGameOver(){
        guessField.disabled = true;
        guessSubmit.disabled = true;

        resetButton = document.createElement('button');
        resetButton.textContent = 'Start New Game';

        document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
        resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
    }
    function resetGame(){
        guessCount = 1;

        const resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
        for(let i = 0; i < resetParas.length; i++){
            resetParas[i].textContent = '';
        }

        resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);

        guessField.disabled = false;
        guessSubmit.disabled = false;
        guessField.value = '';
        guessField.focus();

        lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    }
```

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
const guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
const lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
const lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');
const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
const guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');

let guessCount = 1;
let resetButton;

function checkGuess() {
  let userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
  if (guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';
  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if (guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Game Over';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low';
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high';
    }
  }
  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = ' ';
  guessField.focus();
}

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);

function setGameOver() {
  guessField.disabled = true;
  guessSubmit.disabled = true;
  resetButton = document.createElement('button');
  resetButton.textContent = 'Start New Game';
  document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
}

function resetGame() {
  guessCount = 1;
  const resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
  for (let i = 0; i < resetParas.length; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
  }
  resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
  guessField.disabled = false;
  guessSubmit.disabled = false;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();
  lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultParas">
  <p class="guesses"></p>
  <p class="lastResult"></p>
  <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
</div>

<label for="guessField">Enter a guess: </label>
<input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
<input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">
```

NOTE: The program is working, I'm just hoping someone could make it more clear about the asked question.

Comment: If you add the event handler from *inside* the event handler, that will cause another handler to be added each time it is called. Adding an event handler does not remove other handlers already added.

Comment: `guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess)` will *attach the listener* that will execute the `checkGuess` function when the `guessSubmit` element is clicked. A function has to be executed in order to work. So if `checkGuess` will attach the `checkGuess` function as a listener...how would that happens without first executing `checkGuess`? It's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: If you really want to put that line in a function, you could create an `initializeGame` function, put that line in it, and call it at the end of your script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I will be able to explain you.

```
 function checkGuess(){
     guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess)
 }
```

Above is the javascript `function declaration`, but it does not run until you call it. To run this function you need call it like this `checkGuess()` function.

Since you haven't called the function yet, your code inside the function i.e. `guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess)` never runs. 
`guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess)` code is to bind the click event to your `guessSubmit` element ,So no binding took place yet because it did not run. Due to no binding of event, the click does not execute `checkGuess()` function.

Now when you move `guessSubmit.addEventListener('click',checkGuess)` outside. Javascript runs it this time and binds the click event of `guessSubmit` to `checkGuess` click event. As a result click event triggers the binded function `checkGuess`.